# Why are my two proofs contradicting?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I am checking the commutativity of integration and differentiation of single variable function $A$ with dependent variables $(x,s)$ using two methods. In first method, they are proven to be unequal. In the second, they are proven to be equal. It means I am definitely wrong somewhere in the proof(s). Please point out where am I wrong?

> **Method 1:**
>
> Let $A$ be a function of $s$. Also let $s=f(x)$
>   \begin{align}
> LHS=\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}A \text{ }ds
> =\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}dx
> =\left[  A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}  \right]_a^b
> \end{align}
>
> \begin{align}
> RHS=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\dfrac{dA}{dx} \text{ }ds
> =\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{dA}{dx} \dfrac{ds}{dx}\text{ }dx
> =\left[  A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}  \right]_a^b-\int_a^b \dfrac{d^2s}{dx^2}A\text{ }dx\neq LHS
> \end{align}
>
> The third expression of RHS is obtained by applying integration  by parts.

I came across the following commutativity proof of independent variables $(x\text{ and }y )$ in the internet:

\begin{align}
& \dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}A(x,y) \text{ }dy\\
= &\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{\int_a^bA(x+\Delta x,y)dy
-\int_a^bA(x,y)dy}{\Delta x}\\
= &\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{\int_a^b \left[ A(x+\Delta x,y)-A(x,y)  \right]dy}{\Delta x}\\
= & \int_a^b\dfrac{dA(x,y)}{dx}dy
\end{align}

> **Method 2:**
>
> Applying the same technique to dependent variables:
>
> \begin{align}
> & \dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}A(x,s) \text{ }ds\\
> = &\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{\int_a^bA(x+\Delta x,s+\Delta s)ds
> -\int_a^bA(x,s)ds}{\Delta x}\\
> = &\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow0} \dfrac{\int_a^b \left[ A(x+\Delta x,s+\Delta s)-A(x,s)  \right]ds}{\Delta x}\\
> = & \int_a^b\dfrac{dA(x,y)}{dx}ds
> \end{align}

Comment: Why $\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}dx=\left[  A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}  \right]_a^b$? For example, if $s=x$, then it is obviously wrong.

Comment: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}dx
=\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{d}{dx}   \left[        A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}        \right] dx
=\left[  A \text{ }\dfrac{ds}{dx}  \right]_a^b$$

Comment: When $s=x$ LHS and RHS would be $$\left[  A   \right]_a^b$$

Comment: Thanks that is first mistake.

Comment: If $A=s^2$ and $s=x$, you have $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^b A\frac{ds}{dx}dx =0 \ne[x^2]_a^b$

Comment: Please tell my mistake in method 2

Comment: I think the same mistake is repeated in method 2. Please see

Comment: The definite integral in steps 2 and 3 should be numbers

Comment: The proof you found online works because $x$ and $y$ are independent. In your case, $x$ and $s$ are not independent variables. As a result, you cannot pull your $1/\Delta x$ inside the integral in your "Method 2". In addition, you cannot generally interchange limits and integrals unless certain conditions are met. I don't know why you are trying to prove that the differential operator and integral operator commute in this case. As you can see from velut luna's example, they do not commute if $A(s)$ may be written purely as a function of $s$ (which itself is a function of $x$).

Comment: @bames:What are those conditions? Where can I find them?

Comment: Two examples of such cases are [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and [Monotone convergence theorem for lebesgue integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral).

Comment: I misidentified your error in "Method 2" by thinking of $\Delta x$ as implicitly referring to $x$. You should realize that proof you found online works because $\int_a^b A(x,y) dy$ is still a function of $x$. In your case, $\int_a^b A(s) ds$ will no longer be a function of $x$.-